# What is the best way to get longitude and latitude for an address via Google in java

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to write some java codes getting locations from address. (not in android environment.)

If possible, I want it to be permanent way as long as Google provides geo-location services in somehow.

I think I cannot say Google javascript geolocation apis uses permanent URL to do that, since the api's Object is to come from Google server at runtime.

However I think it seems to be possible that Android might use a permanent URL to do that since Google is not able to change every device's URLs through which devices get the geolocation services.

Am I wrong?
Is there any addressed Google policy concerning it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use the Google HTTP APIs for getting geocoding and reverse-geocoding.

**Geocoding Requests**

A Geocoding API request must be of the following form:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters

where output may be either of the following values:

json (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
xml indicates output as XML

Follow this link for more:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking to use Google GeoCoding then this stuff will be useful to you :

A Geocoding API request must be of the following form:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters

where output may be either of the following values:

```
json (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
xml indicates output as XML
```

To access the Geocoding API over HTTPS, use:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters

HTTPS is recommended for applications that include sensitive user data, such as a user's location, in requests.

In either case, certain parameters are required while some are optional. As is standard in URLs, all parameters are separated using the ampersand (&) character. The list of parameters and their possible values are enumerated below.

Required parameters

```
address — The address that you want to geocode.
     or
latlng — The textual latitude/longitude value for which you wish to obtain the closest, human-readable address. See Reverse Geocoding for more information.
     or
components — A component filter for which you wish to obtain a geocode. See Component Filtering for more information. The components filter will also be accepted as an optional parameter if an address is provided.
sensor — Indicates whether or not the geocoding request comes from a device with a location sensor. This value must be either true or false.
```

Maps API for Business users must include valid client and signature parameters with their Geocoding requests. Please refer to Maps API for Business Web Services for more information.

Optional parameters

```
bounds — The bounding box of the viewport within which to bias geocode results more prominently. This parameter will only influence, not fully restrict, results from the geocoder. (For more information see Viewport Biasing below.)
language — The language in which to return results. See the list of supported domain languages. Note that we often update supported languages so this list may not be exhaustive. If language is not supplied, the geocoder will attempt to use the native language of the domain from which the request is sent wherever possible.
region — The region code, specified as a ccTLD ("top-level domain") two-character value. This parameter will only influence, not fully restrict, results from the geocoder. (For more information see Region Biasing below.)
components — The component filters, separated by a pipe (|). Each component filter consists of a component:value pair and will fully restrict the results from the geocoder. For more information see Component Filtering, below.
```

JSON Output Formats

In this example, the Geocoding API requests a json response for a query on "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA":

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false

We've left the sensor parameter in this example as a variable true_or_false to emphasize that you must set this value to either true or false explicitly.

The JSON returned by this request is shown below. Note that actual JSON may contain less whitespace. You should not make assumptions about the amount or format of whitespace between requests.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.42291810,
               "lng" : -122.08542120
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.42426708029149,
                  "lng" : -122.0840722197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.42156911970850,
                  "lng" : -122.0867701802915
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Here is some sample code that will help you to grab the latitude and longitude :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();                                                                    
            conn.connect();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            StringBuffer sbLocation = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i=0; i != -1; i = isr.read())
            {   
                sbLocation.append((char)i);
            }
            String getContent = sbLocation.toString().trim();   
            if(getContent.contains("results"))
            {
                String temp = getContent.substring(getContent.indexOf("["));
                JSONArray JSONArrayForAll = new JSONArray(temp);
                String lng = JSONArrayForAll.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lng").toString();
                String lat = JSONArrayForAll.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lat").toString();
                System.out.println(" Latitude : " + lat);
                System.out.println(" Longitude : " + lng);
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: But for this you will have to use json-lib-x.x.jar