# How to get longitude/latitude from an URL using Google Place API or any JAVA API

Tags: java, google-places-api

I have an URL (of a restaurant or a place), and I want to get the location (latitude and longitude) of that place using any JAVA API.

With Google Place API, this is possible only after querying the system and giving a description of places we are searching for. But all what we have as input here is the URL.
This is why solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012738/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-longitude-and-latitude-for-an-address-via-google-in) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455394/java-function-that-accepts-address-and-returns-longitude-and-latitude-coordinate) are not responding to what I'm seeking for.

Comment: What sort of URL? A restaurant's website? Could you provide an example?

Comment: A restaurant or a museum website. For example : http://www.myhistorymuseum.org/.

Comment: I really don't think you're going to find a location service that tracks website urls, no.

Comment: So, I have to search for that place with Google Place API (find the place with the same url) and then get the location with the API?

Comment: Given that website, I could barely find their address clicking around as a human being...

Comment: And if you have 1000 websites? :)

Comment: There will be URLs that don't map to a place at all, and then there will be URLs that map to multiple places (e.g. www.kfc.com). Even when you manually type a restaurant name into Google Maps, you sometimes have to tell it which one of the results you want.

Comment: @shoover: you are right! But in my case, all the URLs I have, point to one address, and refer to places in the same region.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to find the address by looking into 
**Bottom Of home page (some sites put their address at footer)**
Find address from following pages linked to the main page **Contact Us**, **About Us**

None of the above approach is guaranteed to retrieve an address ...but is one step closer.
Next option could be to lookup the **whois** to find the registered address. If you are a paid user of lookup service you may be able to lookup address for a particular registrar. But then, there are registries that keeps the address hidden (my own website has the address hidden, it shows the address of service provider).... so not always a success.

You can also lookup other services like **Crunchbase**, and any other directory service as a fallback.

So , let's say we assume you are able to get address of 60-70% websites with all techniques mentioned above. There are situation, where you will end up getting multiple address. You should have a logic to resolve to a particular address. Just think of getting address of Pizza Hut from pizzahut.com :-)

You can add more intelligence...but hope this is good enough to get you started on right direction.

Comment: Sounds to be a bit long. Thank you anyway for the response ! I will try this :)
Any further suggestions are welcome.